# asp.net save username as cookie, then autofill

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authentication

I am trying to save what a user types into the username text box as a cookie, then on subsequent visits have the log-in form auto populate the text box with the cookie value. What am i doing wrong?

This will save the username as the cookie value, but when going back to the log-in page, the cookie value seems to return to null.

I currently have:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Response.Redirect("~/media")
    End If
    Dim UserNameCookie As New HttpCookie("User_Name")
    UserNameCookie.Secure = True
    UserNameCookie.HttpOnly = True
    UserNameCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
    UserNameCookie.Value = UserName.Text
    Response.Cookies.Add(UserNameCookie)

    If Request.Cookies("UserName") IsNot Nothing Then
        UserName.Text = Request.Cookies("UserName").Value.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you see your cookie using the IE developer tools or FireCookie/FireBug?

Comment: Yes, I can see the cookie, and the cookie value as the username entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Username to User_Name. Cookie names must be same.

```
If Request.Cookies("User_Name") IsNot Nothing Then
   UserName.Text = Request.Cookies("User_Name").Value.ToString()
End If
```